# VS Can't clean/build/deploy - Corrupted .NetFramework?

Tags: c#, android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I've started to develop with VS and Xamarin.Android to make my own app. 
Since this morning I can't clean/build/deploy any project, because VS is freezing.
I'm using VS15 Community (latest version) with Xamarin 4.1.2 (other versions did not work aswell). This happen after i did a repair to VS.

I made a logfile and for me it seems like that there are some registry files corrupted due to .NET Framework:

```html
<entry>
    <record>620</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.948</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>621</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.948</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>622</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.948</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>623</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.948</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>624</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.948</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>625</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.948</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>626</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>627</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>628</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>629</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>630</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>631</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>632</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>633</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>634</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>635</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.949</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>636</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>637</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>638</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>639</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>640</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>641</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>642</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>643</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>644</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>645</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>646</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>647</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>648</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>649</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>650</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.950</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>651</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.951</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>652</record>
    <time>2016/09/30 16:52:00.978</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Done loading new toolbox content, total time = 281 ms</description>
  </entry>
```

This happens also at a new blank created app.
I also tried to fix .NET Framework with MS repair tool and deleted the .NET Framework files in control panel. Currently i'm doing "sfc /scannow".
Next will be full reinstall of VS...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen due to a corrupted solution file. In file explorer, navigate to your project's directory, find the .suo file, and delete it. It should be somewhere like MyProject\.vs\MyProject\v14. Or just open your project directory and search for "*.suo". The file will be hidden so make sure you turn on the option to see hidden files.